# Uploading image from Android to my server (Permission Denied)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, resttemplate

I am trying to upload an image selected from gallery to my Springboot server, but when my service try to post the image I get permission denied for the file path. I have added these permissions to my AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- permission below just in case, should not be needed I believe -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I then ask for permission in real time to select the image, and then I want to place it in an inflated view where the user can provide more details about the image, then add it to a report which I will later post.

Since I got this permission trouble I also asked for permission again when I try to submit this Report object containing the images (Uri).

But still I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200206_120434.jpg (Permission denied)
```

Every hit I find on this error on google will point to someone who don't ask for this real-time permission, but I even do it once to much I believe.

This is some related snippets of my code:

```
else if (view.getId() == R.id.stubNewBreedingReportSelectImageButt) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                } else {
                    getPhotoFromPhone(); // this starts the intent to pick an image
                }
            } 
        }

else if (view.getId() == R.id.stubNewBreedingReportSubmitButt) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
                } else {
                    submitNewBreedingReport();
                }
            } 
        }
```

This is from my onClick(View view) method. The first one works since I am allowed to pick an image from the gallery. The second one should probably not need to check the permissions based on every example I have found of projects uploading images from android.

In my onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method I inflate this "add image details view". I also store the selected Uri as a private Uri selectedImg in the activity for future use. This all seems to work pretty much fine.

Then when I submit the image (in the submitNewReport() method) I use an ExecutorService (java class) to start a new async thread for the upload. In this Callable<> I get an instance of Springs RestTemplate and try to post the image, but when my restTemplate try to call and fetch the file from my Uri I get the permission denied.

This is the upload method in my apps ImageService:

```
public Gallery uploadPictureWithInfo(Uri uri, Map<String,Object> imgParams, Context context) {
        if (uri.getPath() != null) {
            File resourceFile = new File(getPathFromUri(uri,context));
            //if (resourceFile.exists()) {
                Gallery saved = null;
                Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(PARAM_FILE, new FileSystemResource(resourceFile));
                if (imgParams.get(PARAM_GALLERY_ID) != null || (long) imgParams.get(PARAM_GALLERY_ID) > (long) 0)  {
                    params.put(PARAM_GALLERY_ID, imgParams.get(PARAM_GALLERY_ID));
                    if (imgParams.get(PARAM_DESCRIPTION) != null) {
                        params.put(PARAM_DESCRIPTION, imgParams.get(PARAM_DESCRIPTION));
                    }
                    if (imgParams.get(PARAM_PHOTOGRAPH) != null) {
                        params.put(PARAM_PHOTOGRAPH, imgParams.get(PARAM_PHOTOGRAPH));
                    }
                    if (imgParams.get(PARAM_USER_ID) != null && (long) imgParams.get(PARAM_USER_ID) > 0) {
                        params.put(PARAM_USER_ID, imgParams.get(PARAM_USER_ID));
                    }
                    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, AquaDbConfig.getImageHeaders());
                    ResponseEntity<Gallery> responseEntity =
                            restTemplate.exchange(AquaDbConfig.getApiUrl() + "/images/uploadImgWithInfo", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Gallery.class);
                    if (responseEntity.hasBody()) {
                        saved = responseEntity.getBody();
                    }
                    return saved;
                }
            //}
        }
        return null;
    }


public static String getPathFromUri(Uri uri, Context context) {
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,filePath, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        c.close();
        return picturePath;
    }
```

I commented out the check for the file.isExist() to get past that test since it wont generate a stack trace otherwise.

So my question is HOW do I get to read the image file when I POST it to the server? I read a little about FileProvider class, but it seems to me that it is used to send files through Intents to new Activites or other Apps. It don't seem to me like it is intended for this because I never leave my Activity exept for picking the image in the gallery. The diffrent steps of creating this ReportedBreeding object is handeled by inflated ViewStubs and not new activites. Also the Uri I use don't refer to any directories I created for my app but rather the users image gallery (external storage).

I also tried to declare my ImageService as a Service in the android manifest, even though I'm not sure we talk about the same kind of service. I then added it this permission but it made no diffrence:

```
        <service
            android:name=".service.MyImageFactory"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
        </service>
```

If you know how to get the permission all the way to this RestTemplate POST method (which noone else seems to need in my reviewed examples) or how I can get around this problem, please share! I'm starting to get a little frustrated and stuck. The problem to me is Why do android require yet another permission check and how do I provide it or work around it in my uploadPictureWithInfo(..) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try asking the permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE before getPhotoFromPhone()

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I was so sure I only needed READ permission based on all the examples I've read but perhaps I was just confused. Why is it considered writing when I "copy" a file for upload though? Is it because I do an action other than just plain reading with their files? Anyway, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

For Android 10 this may be the permission issue, there are two solutions for that to handle for now. First method is to permission to manifest Application tag: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

The other one is to use openFileDescriptor

```
val parcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "r", null)
val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)

fun ContentResolver.getFileName(fileUri: Uri): String {

    var name = ""
    val returnCursor = this.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)
    if (returnCursor != null) {
        val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
        returnCursor.close()
    }

    return name
}

val file = File(context.cacheDir, getFileName(context.contentResolver, fileUri))

val parcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "r", null)

parcelFileDescriptor?.let {
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
    val file = File(context.cacheDir, context.contentResolver.getFileName(fileUri))
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
}
```

Comment: After adding solution one to manifest, it worked for me. I am also using file provider. with it. thanks a lot.